# this[field] alternative in Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

There is a very convinient way to store some render-independent data in React Class by creating a field for it.

For example, if I making several forms, each appearing only at certain step and want to save its data after each step, in Class I will do this:

```
/*in class*/

data = [];

saveData = (field) => {
  this.data.push(field);
};
```

But how can I do the same in functional component if there is no "this", and all scope variables re-creating on each render?

Comment: My guess is you need to actually save it in the state since it's data you want persisted through the renders. That or use a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For render-independent-data, the [recommended way is to use a ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables). The `useRef` hook exposes an object whose `current` property is mutable, you can attach any values that you want persisted across re-renders to it.

```
const data = useRef([]);  // <-- initial value

saveData = (field) => {
  this.data.current.push(field);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The main issue of using a simple variable in a functional component is that it will reinitialized on each render. You can solve this problem with `useRef`, since the data is retained when the component rerenders, and changing it doesn't cause rerender.

Click `add` several times, and then click `render` (forcing render via `useState`);

```js
const { useState, useRef } = React;

const Demo = () => {
  const [v, render] = useState(0);
  
  const data = useRef([]);
  
  const saveData = (field) => {
    data.current.push(field);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => render(Math.random())}>Render</button>
      
      <button onClick={() => saveData(1)}>Add</button>
      
      <div>
        {data.current.toString()}    
      </div>
    </div>  
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo />,
  root
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```